# Reading csv in python pandas and handling bad values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am using pandas to read a csv file. The data are numbers but stored in the csv file as text. Some of the values are non-numeric when they are bad or missing. How do I filter out these values and convert the remaining data to integers.

I assume there is a better/faster way than looping over all the values and using `isdigit()` to test for them being numeric.

Does pandas or numpy have a way of just recognizing bad values in the reader? If not, what is the easiest way to do it? Do I have to specific the dtypes to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv` has the parameter `na_values`:

```
na_values : list-like, default None
    List of additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN
```

where you can define these bad values.

Comment: Great. This seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to use na_values if the string is column dependent?  For instance, I have some columns where negative values are bad, but others where they are fine.

Comment: No @Shawn. Ideally you cannot na_values to perform differently for each columns. Handling negative values should be done while Data Pre-Processing / Cleaning

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a custom list of values to be treated as missing using `pandas.read_csv` . Alternately you can pass functions to the `converters` argument.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy provides the function [`genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) specifically for this purpose.  The first sentence from the linked documentation:

> Load data from a text file, with missing values handled as specified.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought Pandas was supposed to be a higher level add-on. I was expecting this functionality there. So just use that and convert it to a data frame?

Comment: @Dave31415: I don't know exactly how your data looks like, but this is the approach I'd try first.

Comment: If `pandas.read_csv` does not do what you need please create an issue on GitHub: http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues