# I am building a decision tree using python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to drop rows with any NaN values in my dataset.The dimension of my dataset is 9733*123.

Here is the code to drop rows with any NaN value :

```
dataset.dropna(how='all')
print(dataset)
```

Even after running this I am unable to clean my data in csv file. 
Can you guys help?

Comment: As with a huge number of pandas methods, it does not work in-place. Either reassign the result back: `dataset = dataset.dropna(how='all')` or pass the `inplace` argument: `dataset.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)`

Comment: How does this have anyhting to do with a decision tree?

Comment: @Jaba I am cleaning the data first. I mentioned in case of decision tree i have to do something different then others can inform me.

Comment: @roganjosh the inplace thing doesnt work. Any other thing i can do?

Comment: Please paste a sample of the data. There are many reasons for this. For e.g. it may not actually be NaN then you can specify what value is same as `Nan`. You can even remove `na` values when loading data. A sample of this data would help to answer this.

Comment: @AbhishekDujari the data has NA values. how do i specify to drop NA and not NaN?

Comment: Ok there are a couple of things I can't tell from your question. But this is a good answer to your questions assuming you read_csv() or similar import method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514590/reading-file-with-missing-values-in-python-pandas The idea is that within the dataframe the values should be of certain type and then they will be interpreted as Nan or INF or zero. Otherwise you will end up with mixed data types.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html): if you want to drop rows “with **any** NaN values”, use `how='any'` (the default value); and to modify the dataframe instead of making an edited copy, use `inplace=True`. All together:

```
dataset.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: As a general suggestion, if you're using a function from pandas (or any library), and it doesn't do what you think it should, take a look at the documentation. Especially with core Python, NumPy and pandas, the documentation is very thorough and can answer a lot of questions.

Comment: why the downvote?