# Replace value with the average of it's column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `csv` file with multiple columns containing numeric values. However, some rows are missing a value in one or more columns. The missing value is denoted by 'x'.

How would I replace all the missing values ('x') with the average of all values in their column using Pandas?

```py
df=  pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas DataFrame: replace nan values with average of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689823/pandas-dataframe-replace-nan-values-with-average-of-columns)

Comment: Also [reading file with missing values in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514590/reading-file-with-missing-values-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to recognize is the columns that have 'x' in them are not integer datatypes. They are object datatypes.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df

    Col1    Col2
0   1   22
1   2   44
2   3   x
3   4   88
4   5   110
5   6   132
6   7   x
7   8   176
8   9   198
9   10  x

df.dtypes

Col1     int64
Col2    object
dtype: object
```

In order to get the mean of Col2, it needs to be converted to a numeric value.

```
df['Col2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Col2'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')

df.dtypes
Col1    int64
Col2    Int64
dtype: object
```

The df now looks like so:

```
df 

Col1    Col2
0   1   22
1   2   44
2   3   <NA>
3   4   88
4   5   110
5   6   132
6   7   <NA>
7   8   176
8   9   198
9   10  <NA>
```

Now we can use fillna() with df['Col2'].mean():

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].fillna(df['Col2'].mean())

df
    Col1    Col2
0   1   22
1   2   44
2   3   110
3   4   88
4   5   110
5   6   132
6   7   110
7   8   176
8   9   198
9   10  110
```

Comment: "The first thing to recognize is the columns that have 'x' in them are not integers. They are objects." Their dtypes are `object`. The actual columns aren't themselves integers, even if they contain only integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
avg = df[column].mean()
df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda v: avg if v=="x" else v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run into problems taking the mean of columns that have non-numeric values such as 'x'. You'll have to fix that first, such as with `df = df.replace('x',np.nan)` (this works only if `x` is the only non-numeric value) and then you can do`df = df.fillna(df.mean())`. If you start out with integers, the columns with `x` in them will be converted to float (even the rows that weren't replaced), so if you don't want that, you'll have to do more work.